# modify Action Bar Sherlock theme to have no action bar

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using ABS for my application. But I do not want my start screen (the first activity) to have action bar. How should I modify the theme to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set your activity's theme attribute in AndroidManifest.xml file to one of the following based on your requirement:

- android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar"
- android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar

Answer (score 2):

call `hide()` on your ActionBar object, inside the `onCreate()` of your `FirstActivity`

if you are using Sherlock

```
 getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: this serves the purpose of hiding the action bar after the activity is created. it will cause the app to show the action bar and then hide it, which does not look very nice.

Answer (score 0):

add following code in your activity :

```
 ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    ab.hide();
```